# Running long experiments from a web interface

Tags: design-patterns, grails, web-applications

I'm building a research web app that runs a long batch analysis that can last hours.
I'm using **Grails** but I think this is a general design issue.
The batch process can be started by a URL, e.g.

http://mydomain/experiment/run?a_lot_of_params

And this page returns info about the experiment (whose data are stored in the back end and are accessible through another web interface).
e.g.

```
Experiment finished: results available at 
http://mydomain/experiment/data/myexperiment.xml
```

The problem with this approach is: if the experiment lasts a few minutes it's fine to leave a web page waiting. But what happens if the experiment lasts 10 hours? What if the user closes the page?
Is there a correct design pattern to follow for this type of situation?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

You can give user a token and make them enter that token to view the status of the process.

At the end of the process you can notify user via email/call/sms .

Answer (score 0):

Is the batch process asynchronous? If not, you'll need to make it run in another thread. An example:

```
class BatchController {

    def batchExecutionService // has the logic to run the batch operation

    // this should probably only take POST requests, but that's left as a later exercise
    def execute = {

        def batchId

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            batchExecutionService.executeBatch(batchId, params)
        }).start()

        render batchId // could also set response status to 202 Accepted
    }

    def check = {
        render batchExecutionService.getStatus(params.batchId)
    }

    def retrieve = {
        if(batchExecutionService.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {
            // error response, could be 404 if report is not created yet, or something else
        }
        render batchExecutionService.getReport(params.batchId)
    }
}
```

The above implementation is pretty crude, but conveys the general message. A couple notes on it:

- You probably wouldn't want to just new-up a `Thread` and use it, there are better ways to do it (but would yield a more complicated example). A possible solution would be the [BackgroundThread](http://grails.org/BackgroundThread+Plugin) plugin or [Quartz](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) plugin.
- Arguably, the `execute` action shouldn't take GET requests with query parameters like you're currently doing. But that's an entirely different discussion. See [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for a reference.